# MongoDB / Asp.Net Core remove method error with "filter"

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I am working on a Url Shortener in Asp.Net Core and using MongoDB. 
I currently have a working Get method and a working Create method.
I ran into an issue with my Delete method and this is the message I get:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition)', candidates
>   are: System.Threading.Tasks.Task
>   DeleteOneAsync(MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken)(in interface
>   IMongoCollection)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task
>   DeleteOneAsync(this
>   MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken) (in class
>   IMongoCollectionExtensions)

The error has something to do with this ".DeleteOneAsync(**filter**);" in my 'ShortUrlRepository' class:

```
 public async Task<ShortUrl> Delete(ShortUrl su)
        {
            var filter = Builders<Url>.Filter.Eq("Su", su);
            return await _db.Urls.DeleteOneAsync(filter);
        }
```

My ShortUrlsController class seems to be working just fine but I will post it in case:

```
namespace ShortenUrls.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/codes")]
    public class ShortUrlsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ShortUrlRepository _repo;
        //private readonly IShortUrlService _service;

        public ShortUrlsController(ShortUrlRepository repo  /*IShortUrlService service*/)
        {
            _repo = repo;
            //_service = service;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
        {
            var su = await _repo.GetAsync(id);

            if (su == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(su);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] ShortUrl su)
        {
            await _repo.CreateAsync(su);
            return Ok(su);
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete (ShortUrl su)
        {
            try
            {
                if (su == null)
                    return new NotFoundResult();
                await _repo.Delete(su);
                return Ok("Deleted Successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.ToString());
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I have tried other remove methods but have gotten similar errors so maybe I am missing something?

If anyone can offer some suggestions I would greatly appreciate it as I am new to Asp.Net Core and I am having very little success finding a solution to this error. If I can provide anymore information **please** let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating the variable 'r' and returning it** solved the 'Argument 1 error':

```
public async Task<bool> Delete(ObjectId id)
        {
            var filter = Builders<ShortUrl>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id);
            var r = await _db.Urls.DeleteOneAsync(filter);
            return r.DeletedCount > 0;
        }
```

I made other changes that were **unrelated to this error** but were necessary to make the Delete method work properly. Here are the changes I had to make to my 'ShortUrlsController' class:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete (string id)
        {
            return (await _repo.Delete(ObjectId.Parse(id)))
             ? (IActionResult) Ok("Deleted Successfully")
             : NotFound();
        }
```